# PHPStorm - Don't add ="" to boolean attribute auto-complete

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying out PHPStorm 8.0.3 and it's driving me nuts that when adding boolean attributes to an input that it adds the `=""` in there if you do the auto-complete, but I can't figure out how to turn it off.

I want:
`<input type="text" required >`

Not: `<input type="text" required="">`

Comment: Which version of PhpStorm are you using? In latest version of PhpStorm 9.0 (PS-141.1224 with bundled plugins enabled) this type of attributes are working as expected with PHP & HTML files.

Comment: 8.0.3 - I've updated the question

Comment: You may give it a try - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program